# Lost project templates in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

After installing latest update for VS2017, I lost almost all the project templates for starting new project. I get following message when starting new project.
 [image]
I uninstalled and then reinstalled some “Workloads” using new installer without success.
After searching web for solution, I tried to install “NuGet Package Manager” using Extension manager, but seems there is no NuGet Package Manager for VS2017.
Any jugar/solution please?

Comment: try repair or reinstalling all of visual studio 2017.

Comment: Thanks Ken, I am in the process of repair. Taking hours. Let us see what happens. I will update the results if it complete repair in this century :) :).

Answer (score 0):

Repairing VS2017 solved the problem. Is it not a very long route?